# Waiting for data from job.await() to utilise inside Composable

Tags: async-await, kotlin-coroutines, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I am iterating over a loop to render UI inside composable.
Under each iteration, I want to perform some kind of sorting and filtering to the child list (which i want to perform inside async {}) and use that child list to render UI.

Is there a way to wait for the async{} to complete and then render UI?

```
  @Composable
  fun MyTree(data: MutableList<Tree>) {
    LazyColumn {
      itemsIndexed(data) { index, tree ->

        // Wanted to perform this operation inside async and use the result to be passed to composables below
        val stems = tree.stems
          ?.sortedBy { it.age }
          ?.filter { it.living != 0 }

        when (tree.type) {
          TYPE1 -> Tree1(stems)
          TYPE2 -> Tree1(stems)
          TYPE3 -> Tree1(stems)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
@Composable
fun MyTree(data: MutableList<Tree>) {

    // maintain the data you want to use in this composable
    // this seem violate the prince "single source truth", but worked
    val stems = remember {
        mutableStateListOf<Tree>()
    }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = data, block = {
        //  this block will run only if params key1 change
        val stems = tree.stems
            ?.sortedBy { it.age }
            ?.filter { it.living != 0 }
    })


    LazyColumn {

        itemsIndexed(data) { index, tree ->

            // now can use the data stems
            when (tree.type) {
                TYPE1 -> Tree1(stems)
                TYPE2 -> Tree1(stems)
                TYPE3 -> Tree1(stems)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is LaunchedEffect executes in background? and not on the main thread?

Comment: LaunchedEffect executes in background, but still on the main thread. Actually, it uses Coroutine

Comment: I want to perform some task in background and then once it gets done, want to switch to main thread to excecute composable function. Is this possible?

Comment: do some computation tasks you can just use Coroutine, but if  you really want to do task in separate thread, you can use 
```async(Dispatchers.XXX) { you actions} ```